# How to access remotely PgAdmin4?

Tags: pgadmin-4

I Try access pgAdmin4 via browser instaled in another Notebook with Linux Ubuntu 16.04 in the same network in my house, but not access.
In localhost... Ok[image]

But REMOTELY... DOES NOT ACCESS
[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin.

Answer (score 12):

You need to add the following config options:

**DEFAULT_SERVER = '0.0.0.0'**

in **config_local.py** (in "pgAdmin4" folder).

If you also want to change the default port then also add

**DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT = 5050**

Comment: I added DEFAULT_SERVER and now I'm faced with a login page (?) with email (??) and password. Any idea what to do with this?

Comment: How did you login earlier when you were using on local pc? Use the same login credentials to login into pgAdmin4.

Comment: I never had to login - the app just opened.

Comment: Are you able to login into pgAdmin4 from localhost without email/password ?

Comment: @MurtuzaZ, I'm able, and I think Elad Tabak too. It usual pgAdmin4 behaviour when  accessing through http://127.0.0.1

But when access through any other IP or domain name, even through http://localhost, it requests login and password. And I do not know, what password must I use.

Comment: reading the documentation I've added the config_local.py next to the config.py file only with the DEFAULT_SERVER: '0.0.0.0' and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

First change the line in config.py from **DEFAULT_SERVER = '127.0.0.1'** to **DEFAULT_SERVER = '0.0.0.0'**

Config.py is located in the same directory as pgAdmin4:

```
sudo find / -name "*pgAdmin4"
```

Start pgAdmin4 in the same directory (use tmux or as service to keep in background):

```
sudo python3 pgAdmin4.py
```

If you don't know the login, you can delete/move this file and restart pgAdmin.py:

```
sudo find / -name "*pgadmin4.db"
```

This should work on both Ubuntu Server and Desktop. You should preferably keep the 127.0.0.1 and use nginx or Apache in front.

Answer (score 1):

Weird enough, in my case I have to manually run the command

```
$ pgadmin4
```

and then the dashboard will be presented in the default browser automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on ubuntu 20.04 
`apt install pgadmin4-apache2` 
`nano /usr/share/pgadmin4/web/config.py` 
Change 127.0.0.1 by 0.0.0.0 
Don't forget to copy the key in the shell when you launch pgadmin4 in the remote web browser by replacing 127.0.0.1 by pgadmin4 host IP
E.G. : Something like this in your remote web-browser
http://192.168.1.56:43223/?key=5f45c8ee-4593-41d0-9ae1-06d6dd1d8280
PS : If you don't find config.py
`apt install mlocate`
`updatedb`
`locate pgadmin4 | grep config.py$`
All commands are in root don't forget sudo if you are not root

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to open pgadmin client at server.

I suggest you to install pgadmin client from where you want to connect this , add server in pgadmin and do connect.